# How to replace / update DataRow in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, ado.net, datarow

I am trying to update individual record in SQL table. So, I have `DataGridView` view of that table, and when some row is selected in table and Update button is clicked, new Update `Form` is opened.

Main Form passes `DataRow` row parameter to new `Form`, and when update is over, row is returned to Main Form. Code example is about like this in Main Form:

```
private void btnUpdateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Some code to extract DataRow
  FormUpdateUsers updateUser = new FormUpdateUsers(row, new Action<DataRow>(onUserUpdated));
  updateUser.Show();
}
```

When Update Form finishes update, it invokes action and returns row to Main Form, as shown below.

```
public partial class FormUpdateUsers : Form
{

private DataRow row;
private Action<DataRow> action;

public  FormUpdateUsers(DataRow row, Action<DataRow> action)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.row = row;
        this.action = action;
    }

    private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Some code for updatin a database
    action.Invoke(row);
    }
}
```

Question is, how to insert returned row bask to `DataGridView` and replace the outdated one? Any suggestions?

```
private void onUserUpdated(DataRow row)
{
// Update DataGridView?
}
```

Comment: Two questions: how do you get the row that you pass to the second form, and would direct updating of the original data work for you? If you simply pass the datarow to the second form then update it your should not need to pass it back - the datatable will be updated automatically since you are working on the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know which row. Do you have any id column already inside dgv (and datarow)?
If so, then you can do:

```
    private void onUserUpdated(DataRow row)
    {
        int idColumn = int.Parse(row["IdColumn"].ToString());
        foreach (DataGridViewRow DGVrow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (idColumn == int.Parse(DGVrow.Cells["IdColumn"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1[i, DGVrow.Index].Value = row.ItemArray[i].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, thanks! But, with a few bugs. When declaring a value, it goes without toString() method. End there was a problem with last, NULL row, but I fixed that, and now it works perfectly. Thanks again!